# Template for Bloomberg terminal

Tags: bloomberg

I'm working on my master's thesis and I need to extract data from the Bloomberg Terminal. I'm rather inexperienced when it comes to using the Terminals many features. The data I need is for the following stock exchanges Botswana, Cote d'Ivoire, Ghana, Kenya, Mauritius, Namibia, Nigeria and Zambia - these 8 countries constitute the S&P Africa Frontier index. I need the following data: Daily stock closing, bid and ask prices, total number of shares outstanding, traded volumes, dividend per share in local currency and converted into US$. These figures I need for the period of 2000-2015. Do anyone know how to set up this as a template? Any help is much appreaciated. Thanks, Mikkel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a quant question at all

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use the Bloomberg Excel Addin instead of the terminal. It is rather intuitive.

To install the Addin :  Go to "Start Menu"  -> "Bloomberg"  -> "Install Excel Addin"

[Quick Start Guide Here.](http://guides.library.yale.edu/c.php?g=296285&p=1974285)